# How do I echo data inside of a javascript function using mysql's fetch array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm using MySql's fetch array to echo various table rows onto a php page. I'm trying to get that same table data to echo inside of a Javascript function as this data needs to echo in two places, but I cannot get the data from inside of an h2 tag to echo inside of a function.

I've tried numerous ways to target the h2 with a class, and I've also tried to get the element by tag.

One piece of data I have been able to grab and put into a function is data from inside of an 'a' tag.

Here is my code if someone is able to help.

PHP --->

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'c3eleme4_marlon', '00000gez!');
mysql_select_db('c3eleme4_contributors');
$res=mysql_query('select * from issue7');

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
    <div class="contributors">
        <h6><?php echo $row['First']; ?> <?php echo $row['Last']; ?></h6>
        <h2 style="color:#ffffff;"><em><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></em></h2>
        <p style="color:#ffd997;"><?php echo $row['Genre']; ?></p>
    <h3 class="ctr-image"><a href="<?php echo $row['Picture']; ?>" id="3e-fancybox" name="<?php echo $row['First'] .' '. $row['Last']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['Picture']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['ALT']; ?>"></a></h3>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Javascript --->

```
function formatTitle(title) {
    return '<div id="3e-fancybox-title">' + (title && title.length ? '<b>' + title + '</b>' : '' ) + '</div>';
}

    $("#3e-fancybox").fancybox({
        'titlePosition' : 'inside',
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect : 'elastic',
        'titleFormat' : formatTitle,
                afterShow: function(){
                   var name = this.element[0].name;
                   var customContent = "<h5 class='fancybox-name'>"+name+"</div>"
                   $('.fancybox-outer').append(customContent);
                }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would probably be inclined to pass this as JSON  and let the client handle all the rendering. There's no reason to have your server do it, and all these `echo`s just look sort of difficult to manage.

Comment: `mysql` is depreciated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: You have to remember that PHP will execute as soon as the page loads or when JavaScript sends information to the PHP page. I would keep your data separate. In other words, use PHP to get information that you hold in an Associative Array that you `echo json_encode($assocArray);` for JavaScript to handle on the Client, where you can create all of your HTML. Of course, there is always the consideration that the Server could be faster than the Client's Browser, when creating the initial code. When Events fire you may use AJAX anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Just by using the jquery selector. Look this working example. I use here two options so that you can access it either by tag or by class:

```js
alert($( "h2" ).text());
alert($( ".myh6class" ).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contributors">
<h6>inside h6 text</h6>
<h2 class="myh6class"><em>inside h2 text</em></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: this won't work in  repeating collections , will always return text of first element in page with matching selector.

Comment: Well, then just access it by the class name and on the itarattion put a unique class name to each element.....ie: `<h2 class="myh6class1"... <h2 class="myh6class2"....<h2 class="myh6class3"`